# GCP VPC Service Control: Allow access to a subset of Service Projects that belong to the same Host Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-vpc

I've the following GCP resources:

- Project "network" peered to a Host Project "Apps1".
- The Project "network" contains a bucket "test-bucket"
- "Apps1" has a VPC with 2 snets: "snet-dev" and "snet-rec"
- "Apps1" attach two Service Projects:

  - The Service Project "project-dev" uses the Snet "snet-dev"
  - The Service Project "project-rec" uses the Snet "snet-rec"

My Service Perimeter protects three projects: network, Apps1 and project-rec. It protects Google Cloud Storage API, Pub/Sub, GKE Connect API and Kubernetes Engine API.

`gsutil ls gs://test-bucket/` gives the following results:

- From Internet:  === KO (expected result)
- From an instance in the Project "network" === OK (expected result)
- From an instance in "project-rec" that uses the Snet from "Apps1" === OK (expected result)
- From an instance in "project-dev" that uses the Snet from "Apps1" === OK (**not expected result**)

**Is it possible to have different perimeters on Service Projects that belong to the same Host Project?** If so, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, VPC Service Controls (VPC-SC) can only segment resources by VPC networks i.e. all VMs / Pods in a Shared VPC network always belong to the same Service Perimeter (segment) created by VPC-SC. Sub-VPC segmentation is currently not supported by VPC-SC.

By adding Apps1 to the Service Perimeter, all sub-nets of the Shared VPC(s) in the host Project are part of that Perimeter. Thus, the product is behaving as expected here as "project-dev", "snet-dev", "project-rec", and "snet-rec" are in the same service perimeter.

Comment: Yes this has been confirmed by google. They will update the documentation in consequence for clarification. I hope this feature will be provided in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Concept of Shared VPC allows you to centrally control VPC assets. However Google Cloud Storage is not a member of VPC, it's part of [public apis](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/public-vs-private). So you may not be able to control bucket access through shared VPC.

I am not sure but if you enable [private google access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options) you could potentially achieve this.

Comment: private google access is already enabled in my tests. If my understanding is good, the idea behind the VPC Service Controls is to secure google services (regardless of whether they belong to this or that other resource) on a per Project basis. This is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, you are right. Can you please share output of `gcloud access-context-manager perimeters describe {PERIMETER_ID}`?

Comment: status:
  resources:
  - projects/xxx837
  - projects/yyy264
  - projects/zzz415
  restrictedServices:
  - pubsub.googleapis.com
  - storage.googleapis.com
  - container.googleapis.com
  - gkeconnect.googleapis.com
title: first_permiter

Comment: {
  "name": "accessPolicies/????655/servicePerimeters/first_permiter",
  "status": {
    "resources": [
      "projects/xxx0837",
      "projects/yyy264",
      "projects/zzz415"
    ],
    "restrictedServices": [
      "pubsub.googleapis.com",
      "storage.googleapis.com",
      "container.googleapis.com",
      "gkeconnect.googleapis.com"
    ]
  },
  "title": "first_permiter"
}

Comment: Cloud storage I think gets connected over `restricted.googleapis.com` when you use private link. So if you add the above domain in there then it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

storage.googleapis.com resolves to 199.36.153.7, 199.36.153.5  199.36.153.6 or 199.36.153.4

Still not working as expected.